# Intent of Notification does not follow my url

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-intent, notifications

I've got an app that uses Firebase for sending notifications. When I send them, and the notifications shows up, the style is provided, but the rest of the notification is not as described

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lascanadaslogo)
            .setContentTitle("Titulo")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
            .build();
```

Also, when I click it does an intent, but instead of doing it to my url it does it to my app (MainPage). I show you the entire code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.lascanadas.es/reservas"));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lascanadaslogo)
                .setContentTitle("Titulo")
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager2 =  (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager2.notify(0, notification);

        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Firebase` Console for Notification then if your user is not using your app (app is on background) then you have no control over Notification all will be done by Firebase SDK and a click on the notification will open the `Launcher Activity` (`MainActivity`). But if your user is using your app (on foreground) then your `onMessageReceived()` method will be called and so your logic will work. But it always happens when your user is not using your app, so I will advice you to use Data Messages using a server probably. It is even easier with a Server. From there your `onMessageReceived` will always be called and you can retrieve the data simply be:

```
Map<String,String> your_data = remoteMessage.getData;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. I have a raspberry as a server. Which is the program I have to use for it?

Comment: @Jorge. I know there is a simple alternative for that for sure. I will help you with it. `johnnnoni@gmail.com`. Long discussions are discouraged in comments. Use my email then.

Answer (score 0):

When a notification message is sent to the app while it is in the background, `onMessageReceived()` is not invoked; the notification is generated by the SDK.  This is explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages):

> **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. In
>   this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
>   A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

If you want `onMessageReceived()` to always be invoked so that you can control the notification generation, you need to send a [data message instead of a notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).